# Android: Plugins, the best approach

Tags: android, plugins

I want to add (preferably in-app) purchases in form of plugins to my Android app.

The user would buy an 'item' off Play Store which will activate a plugin in the app. The purchace will 'stay' if you reinstall the app or use another device with the same Google Play-account so you wouldn't need to buy it again.

I have a couple of ideas on how the **purchase** could work:

- **Shared Preferences**
  After the purchase a simple boolean could tell the app if it is activated or not.
- **Backend confirmation**
  When a purchase is made it's saved in my backend system.
- **Seperate 'apps'**
  That you can buy off Play Store and use as confirmation (works for all using the account i guess?)

### What is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

In-app Billing API is **the way** to do what you want.
It is near your second option, but the backend is Google's and not yours.

Please read more about official API https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#purchase